# microsoft dynamics nav 2009, show/hide control

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I have a control on a form that I want to hide.

But if I do the following action:

```
LocFrmQuoteInfo.Control1000000002.VISIBLE(false);
```

I get the error:

> Unknow variable: Control1000000002

but `Control1000000002` is the name of the control.

Thank you

But I have a form 50007 and I want to have access controls on a other form. But On Form 50007 I dont have access on the controls of the other form. So I mad a function on the other form, like this:

```
IF Option = 1 THEN
   CurrForm.hallo.VISIBLE(TRUE);
   CurrForm.FromOrder.VISIBLE(FALSE);
 IF Option = 2 THEN
  CurrForm.hallo.VISIBLE(FALSE);
  CurrForm.FromOrder.VISIBLE(TRUE);
```

And then in form 50007 I do this:

```
LocFrmQuoteInfo.FnOrderOfferte();
```

But how to get access to option 1 or option 2 in form 50007?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you might want to break this edit into a second question as the answer is quite different from the display part

Comment: Waht do you mean? IT is the same question

Comment: The first question was about accessing a control with the default value, the edit changes the question to accessing a control from a separate form which doesn't really lend it self to the 1:1 answer format of SO.

Comment: oh ok. But I mean the same

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution to your question is that you need to set a non-default name for the property (Shift+F4) so it shows up in the C/AL Symbols Menu (F5) which will then allow you to reference it and assign values to it in the application.

I have not found where that is referenced, but I would assume it is there to prevent the symbols menu from having every control listed on it in some of the very large reports, forms and other objects.

This would allow you to write something like 
    CurrForm.TextboxToHide.VISIBLE(FALSE);

You can also set this directly on the property of the object if it will be hidden for all users, which does not require changing the default name of the control.